# private static instance variables and inheritance

Tags: java, inheritance, static, private

How does java handle private static variables in child classes?

eg.

```
class Parent
{
    private static int instanceVar = 0;
}

class Sub1 extends Parent
{
    public void () printVar(){
        System.out.println(Super.instanceVar);
    }
}
```

I know this is a simple question, but I haven't seen it covered elsewhere on StackOverflow.

Thanks

Jason

Comment: What do you mean by handling ?

Comment: Did you try compiling that code?

Comment: you should try and run it first.

Comment: Do this question deserves upvote?

Answer (score 1):

`public void () printVar(){}` and `Super.instanceVar` will not compile. To access `instanceVar` from child class, the var must be `protected`, instead of `private`. You can't use `super` to access `static` variables. You must access this way: `Parent.instanceVar`